# Need UIView to autoresize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have made a custom UIView which is shown when the user hits a button in the navigationbar. I make my view's in code. In my loadview I set the autoresizing masks and the view loads correct on screen. However the UIView which is shown when the user taps the button does not resize even when I have set the autoresizing masks.

```
UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 416.0)];
blackView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Do I need to use s`elf.view.frame.size.width` and `self.view.frame.size.height` instead? And if I do why? Does not resizing masks work outside of loadView?

Thank you for your time:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `autoresizingMask` affects how a view will behave when its superview`s frame changes. if all you are doing is showing the`blackView`when you tap a button, then`blackView` will have whatever frame you initially set for it.

If this isn't enough info, please post some more code around how you are configuring and displaying `blackView` and it's superview and explain more about what situations you are expecting `blackView` to resize in. Rotation is one of them, if that's what you're concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I hope you've done this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Let's say the view that needs resizing is: view2
The view that has view2 as a subview is: view1

While creating view1 you would declare it as:

```
view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view1 setNeedsLayout];
```

Now in view1's .m file you need to overload the layoutSubviews method as shown:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect frame = view2.frame;
    // apply changes to frame
    view2.frame = frame;
}
```

In case view1 is a view controller's view, you need to do that same thing as above in the willRotate method as shown

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    CGRect frame = view2.frame;
    // apply changes to frame
    view2.frame = frame;
}
```

This is a tried and tested method that I use to handle orientation changes.

Comment: Bear in mind that in the willRotate method, the view controller has not rotate yet so using self.view.frame to render new frames will not get you what you want. You have to use "toInterfaceOrientation" to set the new frames.

Comment: hmm.. this question doesn't seem to be about orientation changes. this answer will only add confusion if the OP is just trying to figure out how autoresizing behavior works.